# Javascript - eval() `{}` expression

Tags: javascript, eval

Why can a string like `"{opacity: 1.0, width: '132px'}"` not be evaluated using `eval()` as is?

```
eval("{opacity: 1.0, width: '132px'}");

// invalid label
// {opacity: 1.0, width: '132px'}
// ---------------ꜛ

eval("v = {opacity: 1.0, width: '132px'}");

// works!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why can a string like `"{opacity: 1.0, width: '132px'}"` not be evaluated using eval() as is?

Because the text occurs where a statement or block is expected, not an expression, and so the `{` denotes the beginning of a [block](http://es5.github.com/#x12.1), not the beginning of an [object initializer](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.5). (And then `opacity:` is interpreted as a [label](http://es5.github.com/#x12.12) followed by the statement separator [a comma], and then `width:` looks like another label, which is not valid there.)

Putting it in parentheses changes the parsing context so that an expression is expected, and so the `{` opens the initializer. (This is the same reason you see self-executing anonymous functions wrapped in parentheses, e.g. `(function(){ ... })();` rather than just `function(){ ... }();`.)

Comment: More technically, the reason is that the grammar prefers the rule "Block" over the rule "ExpressionStatement" when parsing a [Statement](http://es5.github.com/#x12)

Answer (score 3):

> Why can a string like "{opacity: 1.0, width: '132px'}" not be evaluated using eval() as is?

Because `{opacity: 1.0, width: '132px'}` is invalid javascript as-is. Try putting this statement as-is and you will get a js error. On the other hand `v = {opacity: 1.0, width: '132px'}` is valid javascript.

Comment: `{opacity: 1.0, width: '132px'}` is perfectly valid javascript.

Comment: @thg435, are you sure about that? The following generates a javascript error for me: http://jsfiddle.net/n4yMx/

Comment: This comes down to your definition of "valid", I guess.

Comment: @thg435, yes, my definition of valid is something that a javascript interpreter (which is what the `eval` function does) considers as valid javascript. What's yours definition?

Comment: Your definition is good, it only lacks a noun. Should be: "a valid javascript _program_ is something etc".

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
eval("({opacity: 1.0, width: '132px'})");
```

Comment: Correct answer. This is because `{...}` is an invalid javascript expression, but `(...)` is valid.