# JavaScript eval("{}") return behavior?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

According to the [ECMA-262 Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), the following statements return `1`:

```
eval("1;;;;;")
eval("1;{}")
eval("1;var a;")
```

Ensuring that:

> The value of a StatementList is the value of the last value producing Statement in the StatementList.

Can you explain these different returns ?

```
eval("{}") // undefined
eval("var a={}; a;") // {}
eval("var a={};") // undefined
```

What is the difference between `1;` and `{};` ?

Comment: This is a duplicate, FWIW. (It is just awkwardly hard to find such duplicates on SO :-/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943278/javascript-eval-expression (it's the same idea, but results in different observed semantics due to invalid syntax)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Left alone, `{}` is interpreted as a *block*, not an object. It contains no statements, so does not affect the value of, say, `eval("1;{}")`. To force it to be interpreted as an object, you can use parentheses:

```
eval("1;({})"); // {}
```

Comment: I got it ! I didn't even think about the block thing, thanks ;)

Comment: `"({})"` is sufficient... (for balance with the second part of the post, which does not have a `1;`)

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like `eval` is interpreting `{}` as the delimiters of a code block, and therefore has no inherent value.